# when I use spring mvc and jsp, why my argument can't transfer the value?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

controller file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public ModelAndView hello() {  
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();  
   mv.addObject("message", "Hello World!<br>");  
   return mv;  
} 
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ModelAndView test() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(); 
    mv.addObject("title", "aaa"); 
    return mv;
}
```

hello.jsp:

```
${message}
<jsp:include page="test.jsp" flush="true"/>
```

test.jsp:

```
${title}
bbb
```

when I get localhost:8081/test, it returns

```
aaa bbb
```

when I get localhost:8081/test, it returns

```
Hello World!
bbb
```

why the ${title} can't get the value "aaa", and How can I achieve this.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  You are saying that `get localhost:8081/test` is returning two different outputs.

Comment: @StephenC what I want is get localhost:8081/test and it returns:Hello World! aaa bbb.  But, it returns without "aaa"

Comment: Please fix your question.  It still makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables that you want to use in the view need to be set in the controller. In your code /hello will only set the message and no title, and in /test only the title is set. To fix it you need to change the controller like below. You should also remove "
" from the controller because html should be part of the view (hello.jsp).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public ModelAndView hello() {  
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();  
   mv.addObject("message", "Hello World!<br>"); 
   mv.addObject("title", "aaa"); 
   return mv;  
}
```

Comment: But in /test, I set the $title, and in hello.jsp, I include test.jsp. why do I have to set $title in /hello?

Comment: I have found a solution. Amended hello.jsp to <jsp:include page="/test" flush="true"/>